# ¿ Como quitar la barra de desplazamiento vertical que se genera automaticamente en el <mat-sidenav-container> de Angular material?

Tags: angular, angular-material

En mi `<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">` tengo el `<router-outlet>`. En la siguiente imagen muestro como este `<router-outlet>` esta llamando a `home.componen.html` para mostrar una lista de productos. Como esta lista tiene varios productos, en la vista se genera de forma automática una barra lateral de desplazamiento para poder ver el contenido completo.
Esteticamente no queda bien ya que tengo dos barras laterales, la que esta predeteminada por el navegador y la que se genera en el `<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">`.

Aca la imagen por si no se entendio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hay alguna forma de poder quitar alguna barra para que quede por predeterminada la barra del navegador o la que se esta generando de forma automatica?

aca mi `main-nav.component.html` donde tengo el `<router-outlet>`

```html
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" [ngClass]="{hidden: !(isHandset$ | async)}" fixedInViewport
    [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'" [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
    [opened]="(isHandset$ | async) === false">
    <mat-toolbar>Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content class="caca">
    <mat-toolbar color="primary" class="mat-elevation-z6">
      <button type="button" aria-label="Toggle sidenav" mat-icon-button (click)="drawer.toggle()"
        *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
      </button>
      <mat-icon>eco</mat-icon><span>Bookstore</span>
      <div class="spacer"></div>
      <div class="hide">
        <a mat-list-item routerLink="home">Link 1</a>
        <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
        <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
        <a mat-raised-button color="accent" [routerLink]="'/home'">Login</a>
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <!-- Add Content Here -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

y por las dudas tambien les muestro el `home.component.html` donde hago el listado de los productos

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="book-grid">
        <div class="card" *ngFor="let book of bookList$ | async">       
                <img [src]="linkImg(book.url_image)" [alt]="book.name" class="crop-image">
            <div class="card-header text-center">
                <a routerLink="">{{ book.name }}</a>
            </div>
            <p class="text-center">{{book.price | currency}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias @Excorpion por responder, pero en el link que me pasaste hay una clase .menu-overflow-hidden que quita la barra de desplazamiento que se genera en el mat-sidenav-container, pero al mismo tiempo no deja que pueda ver el contenido completo de la lista de productos, es decir muestra por ejemplo 12 productos de los cuales los ultimos 6 visualmente los muestra cortados y aunque desplaze la barra del navegador no las muestra.

Comment: Puedes agregarle estilos al scroll para hacerlo mas delgado y menos visible por ejemplo colocarlo en color blanco o transparente. 
/* Tamaño del scroll */
.container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 2px;
}
Puedes encontrar detalles en: https://ed.team/blog/personaliza-el-scroll-de-tu-web-solo-con-css o ver el ejemplo: https://codepen.io/Jopzik/pen/xaWzMB/