# ¿Cómo quitar el scroll que se genera con el contenedor <mat-drawer-content> de Angular material?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Necesito quitar el scroll que se genera en ese contenedor ya que uso tabs y el contenedor de este ya tiene el scroll para su propio contenido pero necesito quitar el scroll del contenedor mat-drawer-container pero este genera un contenedor llamado mat-drawer-content y es el que tiene el scroll de la pagina, me sucede lo mismo que en esta pregunta pero al parecer quitaron la respuesta.

**Pregunta:** [¿ Como quitar la barra de desplazamiento vertical que se genera automaticamente en el <mat-sidenav-container> de Angular material?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/407531/como-quitar-la-barra-de-desplazamiento-vertical-que-se-genera-automaticamente)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es simple, solo tienes que agregar ese elemento a tu archivo css principal **style.css** que se genera al crear el app de angular

```
.mat-drawer-content{
    overflow: hidden !important;
}
```

puedes intentarlo sin necesidad del !important pero hay te lo dejo asi por si no te funciona, recuerda que al terminar de cargar tu app los estilos que tienen prioridad al final solo los que están en "src/styles.css", esto lo puedes aplicar con otros elementos de material, bootstrap o los template. espero haberte ayudado ;)

Comment: :0 valla si me funciono, muchas gracias por tu respuesta y explicación

Comment: No hay problema estamos para ayudar. :D

Answer (score 1):

Agrega al elemento que le quieres quitar el scroll los siguientes estilos css

::-webkit-scrollbar{ width: 0} y tambíen {scrollbar-width: none}

Esto haría invisible la barra de scroll, ahora si lo que quieres es que no se pueda hacer scroll solamente agrega {overflow: hidden}
Todo lo mencionado se vería así

```
//Para hacer la barra de scroll invisible

//Chrome, Opera, Edge, Safari
element::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 0;
}

//Firefox
element{
    scrollbar-width: none;
}


//Para eliminar la barra de scroll
element{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Disculpa tu respuesta es correcta, pero el problema esta en que el elemento al que te refieres no existe en mi código es un contenedor que se genera en tiempo de ejecución  ya que es un elemento de material angular llamado contenedor mat-drawer-container que al cargar la pagina este genera el elemento al que te refieres